# Google analytic with iframe. Campaign tracking does'n work

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have problem with custom campaign tracking in Google analytic.
In sns my app embedded with inframe and all link looks like:

```
http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/game/tunerlife?utm_source=source1&utm_medium=Medium1&utm_campaign=CompName
```

but for iframe this param send like custom_args:

```
http://cdn.tuner-life.com/tl/frame_od.htm?authorized=1...custom_args=utm_source%3Dwork%26utm_medium%3Dwork1%26utm_campaign%3Dworkwork&session_...
```

in javascript i parse this param and push _setCampSourceKey and other 2 parameters like in a google documentation :

```
            var custom_args = decodeURIComponent(flashvars["custom_args"]);
            var custom_pairs = custom_args.split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < custom_pairs.length; i++)
                {
                    var c_pair = custom_pairs[i].split('=');
                    if (c_pair[0] == "utm_source")
                        _gaq.push(['_setCampSourceKey', c_pair[1]]);
                    else if (c_pair[0] == "utm_medium")
                        _gaq.push(['_setCampMediumKey', c_pair[1]]);
                    else if (c_pair[0] == "utm_campaign")
                        _gaq.push(['_setCampNameKey', c_pair[1]]);                        
                }
```

but i dont see my custom campaign in GA.
What wrong?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're trying to change the key values but in reality you're changing the key names; don't do that. The utm_source keyname is still "utm_source" with a value of "work" but you're changing the keyname to "work", and theres no "work=work" in the URL so GA isn't recording a hit. Just delete that javascript code entirely.